# Why simple math in JS allocates a lot of memory

Tags: javascript, memory, optimization, node-webkit

Why the below code allocates a lot of memory?

```
Entity3D.prototype._updateEuler = function(elapsed) {
    this.velocity.x += this.force.x / this.mass * elapsed;
    this.velocity.y += this.force.y / this.mass * elapsed;
    this.velocity.z += this.force.z / this.mass * elapsed;

    var initialSpeed = this.speed = vector3.length(this.velocity);
    if (this.speed && this.deceleration)
        this.speed = Math.max(0, this.speed - this.deceleration*elapsed);
    if (this.speed > this.maxSpeed)
        this.speed = this.maxSpeed;
    if (this.speed !== initialSpeed) {
        this.velocity.x = this.velocity.x / initialSpeed * this.speed;
        this.velocity.y = this.velocity.y / initialSpeed * this.speed;
        this.velocity.z = this.velocity.z / initialSpeed * this.speed;
    }

    this.oldPosition.x = this.position.x;
    this.oldPosition.y = this.position.y;
    this.oldPosition.z = this.position.z;
    this.position.x += this.velocity.x * elapsed;
    this.position.y += this.velocity.y * elapsed;
    this.position.z += this.velocity.z * elapsed;

    if (this.speed > 0)
        vector3.normalize(this.velocity, this.heading);
};
```

[image: Heap allocations by functions]

Above screenshot is after running the game for 40 seconds at 60 FPS, with about 200 Entity3D objects updated every frame and `_updateEuler()` was called about 500 000 times during this time.

All properties from above code are regular numbers or simple objects created by object literal: `{'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}` and they are created of course when object is created, not every frame. This means, that above code just does some simple math and assign numbers to properties.

Entity3D is a simple class to represent some game objects, including particles. I'm allocating about 200 of these objects at start and reuse them by resetting their properties instead of allocating whole new instances.

### My questions are:

- Do I read the profiler correctly, does really this function allocates 40 MB of RAM for some reason?
- How do I reduce memory allocation in this function?

Functions used in the above code:

```
function normalize(vector, out) {
    var l = Math.sqrt(vector.x*vector.x + vector.y*vector.y + vector.z*vector.z);
    if (l > 0) {
        out.x = vector.x / l;
        out.y = vector.y / l;
        out.z = vector.z / l;
    } else
        out.x = out.y = out.z = 0;
}

function length(vector) {
    return Math.sqrt(vector.x*vector.x + vector.y*vector.y + vector.z*vector.z);
}
```

### Possible answer:

> Any time a floating point number is assigned to a property of an
>   object or an element of an array, it must first be boxed (allocated on
>   the heap). If your program performs a lot of floating point math,
>   boxing can be costly. You can't avoid boxing when working with object
>   properties, but when operating on arrays, you can use typed arrays to
>   avoid boxing.

From [Writing efficient JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781219.aspx)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it did allocate 40MB across all those 3.6 million calls, but not at once.

Comment: I've put an increment counter inside this function and it counted only ~500 000 calls.